# Problemas ao usar setlocale() em c

Tags: c, windows-10, locale

Olá. Sou novo na comunidade então se eu estiver fazendo algo errado me corrijam por favor.
Estou começando a programar em C, e gostaria de poder usar acentuação nos meus programas. Encontrei materiais sobre isso em vários sites e todos pede para utilizar a biblioteca ***locale.h*** e o comando **setlocale(LC_ALL,"")**. Ja tentei trocar o conteúdo dentro das **""** para **"Portuguese"**, **“Portuguese_Brasil.1252"** e **“pt_BR_utf8”**. A única coisa que acontece é a mudança de caracteres diferentes para outros caracteres que ainda não são o que preciso. Encontrei no site http://linguagemc.com.br/localizacao-de-programas-com-locale-h/ um código que se encontra abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h> //necessário para usar setlocale

int main(void)
{
    printf("\n****** Verificando a localidade corrente ********\n\n");
    printf ("Localidade corrente: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL) );
    printf("Não é possível usar acentuação ou ç corretamente...\n\n");

    printf("\n****** Alterando para a localidade do sistema ********\n\n");

    //alterando para o padrão do sistema operacional
    printf("A localidade corrente agora é %s \n",setlocale(LC_ALL,""));
    printf("Agora não tem mais problema algum!\n");
    printf("Já posso usar acentuação e também o caracter ç...\n\n\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

E a saída desse código no meu computador é:

> ****** Verificando a localidade corrente ********
>
> Localidade corrente: C
>   N├úo ├® poss├¡vel usar acentua├º├úo ou ├º corretamente...
>
> ****** Alterando para a localidade do sistema ********
>
> A localidade corrente agora Ã© Portuguese_Brazil.1252  Agora nÃ£o tem
>   mais problema algum!  JÃ¡ posso usar acentuaÃ§Ã£o e tambÃ©m o caracter
>   Ã§...

Testei o código em um outro computador e funcionou corretamente. Conferi o CLion está em UTF-8, e meu SO está em Português Brasileiro, assim como meu teclado.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h> //necessário para usar setlocale

int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    printf("\n****** Verificando a localidade corrente ********\n\n");
    printf ("Localidade corrente: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL) );
    printf("Não é possível usar acentuação ou ç corretamente...\n\n");

    printf("\n****** Alterando para a localidade do sistema ********\n\n");

     //alterando para o padrão do sistema operacional
    printf("A localidade corrente agora é %s \n",setlocale(LC_ALL,""));
    printf("Agora não tem mais problema algum!\n");
    printf("Já posso usar acentuação e também o caracter ç...\n\n\n");

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```